# onActivityResult RESULT_CODE always 0 (cancel)

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Another weird question. Always getting RESULT_CANCELLED (that's a problem) while working with camera via intent. More relevant context:

I assign setOnClickListener to ImageView in activities' onCreate:

```
this.imSnapshot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

Code of getImageUri method:

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this);
    File dir = cw.getDir("dcim", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(dir, UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.d("DetailsModify.getImageUri", imgUri.toString());
    return imgUri;
}
```

Here is onActivityResult (log line always return 0):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        Log.d("DetailsModify", "onActivityResult code " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

UPDATE: the error was filtered by IDE so I did not notice it originally:

```
CameraActivity:Saved image not found
        java.io.FileNotFoundException
        at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
        at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:119)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:481)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:365)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:341)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.CameraActivity.copyContentToExtraOutputUri(CameraActivity.java:1680)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.CameraActivity.setResult(CameraActivity.java:1639)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.view.CameraWindow.onStoreComplete(CameraWindow.java:1405)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.PhotoController.onStoreComplete(PhotoController.java:879)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.TakenStatus.notifyComplete(TakenStatus.java:83)
        at com.sonyericsson.android.camera.ImageManager$StoreDataHandler.handleMessage(ImageManager.java:960)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: removing this line in onClick gets me back RESULT_OK:
   cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());

Comment: Perhaps the directory "dcim" doesn't exist, thus causing the Intent to return RESULT_CANCELED?

Comment: In documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) it says getDir "Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files.". Will see if file gets created.

Comment: I copy pasted this code and the directory doesn't get created for me.  Also debugging shows the directry trying to be created as "app_dcim" for some reason, weird.  This is how I do the same thing in my app and it works fine: `new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()) + ".jpg");`

Comment: Thanks. It does work with getExternalFilesDir but my goal is to use private storage, not external card.

Comment: You can use getExternalFilesDir for external storage or getFilesDir for internal storage.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: @user1199931, appreciate your efforts. I tested the solution with getFilesDir, but it do not solve the problem. Anyways, I'm starting to think the real problem is because Camera application cannot access my application's private storage (weird, but still). That's why it says FileNotFound. I almost quit on this question, will focus on using external storage in order not to waste time...

Comment: UPDATE2: so far dir.setWritable(true, false) did the trick but still doing more testing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have not received any better solution to my question, sharing what I got on my own. I 
made my problem solved by adding **dir.setWritable(true, false)** to method below, tested on API10:

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this);
    File dir = cw.getDir("dcim", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    dir.setWritable(true, false);
    File file = new File(dir, UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.d("DetailsModify.getImageUri", imgUri.toString());
    return imgUri;
}
```

What it does is it sets permissions allowing Camera to write to application's private location (more info at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean,%20boolean%29). I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To NeviQ-Or's comment:

If

```
    dir.setWritable(true, false);
```

does not work, try using

```
    "absolute_file_path".setWritable(true, false);
```

The former did not work for me, but the latter did.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the theme of the activity.. I tried everything and nothing worked, I was testing with android 11... so I fixed it by removing the following code from the manifest..

android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme"